# Twig Error : Warning: Missing argument 1 for {closure}()

Tags: php, twig

I'm coding an app in PHP for school work and I'm using Twig template engine lonely (without a framework).

I got a file which initialize Twig in my project and I use it in all files that need it.

```php
include_once('./Twig/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php'); 
Twig_Autoloader::register();
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('./templates');    
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'cache' => false,
    'charset' => 'utf-8'
));
```

I have a Twig Function which returns the path to my static files folder. But when I run `addFunction($my_function)` I got the error below :

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for {closure}()

**My Twig function:**

```php
$url_for_static = new Twig_SimpleFunction('static_folder', function () {
$static_folder = "./static" ;
    return $static_folder ;
});

$twig->addFunction($url_for_static);
```

I know this answer is really late but i finally found a solution to my problem. My Twig function declaration was wrong. 
**This worked for me :**

`

```
function blank_space($size=100) {       
    echo "<div class='grid-". $size ." hidden'> <span> hidden </span> </div>" ;
}
$twig->addFunction('blank_space', new Twig_Function_Function('blank_space')) ;
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Twig before, but it seems the closure is called with an argument but you didn't define any arguments in your closure. Try this:

```
$url_for_static = new Twig_SimpleFunction('static_folder', function ($arg) {
    var_dump($arg);
    $static_folder = "./static" ;
    return $static_folder ;
});
```

Comment: @iamphinson please post your answer as an answer to this question. After 48 hours, you can accept that as the best answer. That's the common way to handle such things

Comment: Okay, @WouterJ :) i'm tryin but it's a little hard to include the code in the comment. i use the ` ` but it doesn't work

Comment: @iamphinson as I said, you shouldn't use a comment for that, but typ the answer in the box below (click on the 'Answer your question' button below)

Comment: Thanks ! it's done. i hadn't saw the "Answer your question" button. I removed my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is really late but i finally found a solution to my problem. My Twig function declaration was wrong.

**This worked for me :**

```
function blank_space($size=100) { 
    echo "<div class='grid-". $size ." hidden'> <span> hidden </span> </div>" ; 
} 

$twig->addFunction('blank_space', new Twig_Function_Function('blank_space')) ;
```